# List or auto-complete existing string values, for new plaintext cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a plaintext column in my Google spreadsheet, several rows (cells) of which have already been filled with a limited number of strings, let's say for simplicity "January", "February", "March", etc.

I would like to format the column such that, when entering text in new (empty) cells, rather than having to type the text from scratch, I instead get to choose from a drop-down list populated with the strings that already exist in other cells of that column (all 12 months, in the example above).

Or, alternatively, to have an auto-complete that would suggest, say, "March" and "May", once I start typing "M". Strangely, I haven't seen this basic feature at work in GSheets for a while, even though the EnableAutocomplete option is checked in the menu.

Among the two options, I would prefer the one with the drop-down list over the autocomplete one, but ultimately either would be of massive help. The idea is, once the number of unique strings becomes high (but there is also a lot of repetition), to reduce the chance of making a typo when entering new values just because they happen to differ by one letter from a string that already exists elsewhere.

Is there a way to do this just via the GUI/addons? I know this is possible to do in Excel for the header row (screenshot below), but I don't know of a way to do that also in GSheets, and in either case, what I need is to have this sort of selection list at the cell- rather than at the header-row level.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are looking for is called Data Validation:

[image: 0]

and you can select various options for criteria

Comment: Indeed, thank you! However, when I add a new (unique) string in a new cell, and go on to the next cell, the value just added does not appear in the drop-down list. Do I need to redefine the range with every new unique value added to the column?

Comment: Also, it seems the source range and the target range cannot be the same, whereas I'd like for values that populate the drop-down list to come precisely from the column that I'm applying the Data Validation to

Comment: you can setup a range like A1:A (without ending number) so everything you add in A column will automatically appear in dropdown

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm just being dense, but I keep hitting the "The selected ranges cannot intersect" message, after I selected A1:A as both my CellRange and my CriteriaRange

Comment: well, yes, that kinda makes sense coz if you wouldn't get that error message then you would kinda create circular dependency paradox :) you cant reference the reference

Comment: I don't see the circularity - for a *new* cell I want to be able to choose a value for it based on values that exist in *other* cells from that same column. Looks like the DataValidation feature can only apply to a target column that is different from the source column. Shame. Still, thanks a lot for pointing out the feature to me!